# SwiftUI, iOS: How to access public function inside @main struct from custom internal View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

How to access achieveTo() inside @main struct from CustomInternalView()?

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            CustomInternalView()
        }
    }

    public func achieveTo() {
        // Do stuff
    }
}


struct CustomInternalView: View {
    var body: some View {
         Text("Some")
    }
    .onDisappear {
        // How to call "achieveTo" from here????????????
    }
}
```

In UIKit it is like `UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController as! YourViewController`, How about SwiftUI?

Comment: You don’t, work with state instead like using a State/Binding solution or an EnvironmentObject so that one view changes the state and the other reacts on the change (and calls achieveTo)

Comment: If an answer worked, can you click the green checkmark to accept it?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a closure:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            CustomInternalView {
                achieveTo() /// 2. Assign closure
            }
        }
    }

    public func achieveTo() {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
struct CustomInternalView: View {
    var callParentTask: (() -> Void) /// 1. Define closure
    
    var body: some View {
         Text("Some")
            .onDisappear(perform: callParentTask) /// 3. Call closure
    }
}
```

Note: Your `onDisappear` must be attached to a View inside the `var body: some View {`, not outside.

Answer (score 2):

Another simpler version of what **@aheze** answered:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            
            CustomInternalView()
                .onDisappear() { achieveTo() }

        }
    }
}

func achieveTo() {
    // Do stuff
}

struct CustomInternalView: View {

    var body: some View {
         Text("Some")
    }

}
```